# Which recipes are executed when make is invoked with no arguments?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How does make decide which (if any) recipes are executed when `make` is called without any arguments?

Comment: It's all in the docs: [GNU Make manual, section 9.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals): _"By default, the goal is the first target in the makefile (not counting targets that start with a period)."_

Comment: Ok, I was also looking for something like the .DEFAULT_GOAL variable, I was confused by the fact that I expected .DEFAULT to have that use. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title is somehow confusing, because `make` takes the first `target` if not specified differently (e.g., by using `.DEFAULT_GOAL` or by passing the target name as an argument of `make`). That, however, does not necessarily mean that the first `recipe` is also executed. If `make` considers the target up-to-date, no recipe will be executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ruslan wrote in a comment the answer is a combination of the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` variable and simply the first target defined in the Makefile.

Comment: There is a small caveat, `make` will technically execute first all rules which lead to updated include makefiles: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles